# Type assertion for return value of puppeteer's page.$eval promise

Tags: typescript, puppeteer

I'm writing a nodejs app with puppeteer and have problems regarding the return type of its `page.$eval`.
Consider the following code block:

```js
import puppeteer, { Page } from "puppeteer";

const getValueBySelector = (page: Page, selector: string) => {
  return page.$eval(selector, (el) => el.innerText);
};

interface Prices {
  low: string;
}
(async () => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
  const page: Page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.goto(URL);
  let prices: Prices = {
    low: await getValueBySelector(page, "#low"),
  };
})();
```

According to automatic type infer for `getValueBySelector` the return type for this function is `Promise<puppeteer.ElementHandle<any>>` but I need my `prices.low` value to be a `string`.

So there's a type error on `prices.low` which says:

```
Type 'ElementHandle<any>' is not assignable to type 'string'.ts(2322)
```

How should I use a type assertion here to fix the problem?

Comment: Where are you getting the declaration file? `$eval` returns a `Promise<any>`.

Comment: Here's the source: https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/puppeteer/index.d.ts#L60

Comment: I believe that's wrong. I made a comment here https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/pull/26489/files#r406436105

Comment: Is there something I can do to publish my package without typescript errors while this is being resolved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I commented on the question, I believe it's an error on the definition file. But, `$eval` is nothing more than calling `$` and then calling `evaluate`. So you could do something like:

```
const getValueBySelector = async (page: Page, selector: string) => {
  const el = await page.$(selector);
  if (el)
    return await page.evaluate((el) => el.innerText, el);
};
```